# How can I run the exe file created by Xamarin Studio in Debug directory on OSX?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono

I learn Xamarin Studio with C# for a while. I got confused because I cannot run the exe file in the Debug directory by command 'mono test.ext'. This is the error message below:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
type initializer for Gtk.Container ---> System.DllNotFoundException:
gtksharpglue-2
at (wrapper managed-to-native) 
Gtk.Container:gtksharp_gtk_container_get_focus_child_offset ()
at Gtk.Container..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Gtk.Bin..ctor (IntPtr raw) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Gtk.Window..ctor (WindowType type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MainWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at BuildBoxTool.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Gtk.Container ---> System.DllNotFoundException: gtksharpglue-2
at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Container:gtksharp_gtk_container_get_focus_child_offset ()
at Gtk.Container..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Gtk.Bin..ctor (IntPtr raw) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Gtk.Window..ctor (WindowType type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MainWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at BuildBoxTool.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What shoul I do to solve it? Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for Gtk.Container ---> System.DllNotFoundException:
>   gtksharpglue-2

By default the Mono lib directory is not added to any global dyld path, for details check out the man page for dyld:

man dyld

```
~~~
       DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
              This is a colon  separated  list  of  directories  that  contain
              libraries.  It is used as the default location for libraries not
              found  in  their  install  path.   By  default,  it  is  set  to
              $(HOME)/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib.
~~~
```

So to run your GTK# based 'test.exe' :

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib"
mono test.exe
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you mean that I should run the app with command:"DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib"
mono test.exe". It doesn't work.

Comment: Set the env var DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH to the location of your Mono lib install, assuming you are not running a parallel Mono install on OS-X that would be "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib" and then 'mono yourexenamehere.exe"